# Sorting and Filtering breaks when using a Complex ViewModel w/ Kendo UI grid

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-ui-mvc, kendo-ui-grid

I am using Kendo UI for ASP.NET Core. I am using a Kendo Grid and need the following features to work:
Sorting, Filtering, Editing (w/ Customers ComboBox in cell). It turns out that you need a Complex View model for the Editor Template to work as per [this documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/templating/editor-templates#configuration-Create), but the complex view model breaks the grid's Sorting and Filtering functionality. Since the grid tries to sort and search on an Object instead of a single field.

I have a ViewModel that looks like the following:

```
public class ProjectViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [UIHint("CustomersEditor")]
    public CustomerViewModel Customer { get; set; }
}
```

I am using it as the model for my Kendo grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
      .Name("grid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(c => c.Customer).Title("Customer").ClientTemplate("#= Customer.Name#");
          columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(300);
      })
      .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
      .Sortable()
      .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
      .Pageable(pageable => pageable
          .Refresh(true)
          .PageSizes(true)
          .ButtonCount(5))
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Ajax()
          .PageSize(20)
          .Model(model =>
          {
              model.Id(item => item.Id);
          })
          .Create(update => update.Action("Projects_Create", "Projects"))
          .Read(read => read.Action("Projects_Read", "Projects"))
          .Update(update => update.Action("Projects_Update", "Projects"))
          .Destroy(update => update.Action("Projects_Destroy", "Projects"))
      )
      )
```

As you can see I am specifying the property Customer as a bound column and setting the Client Template to be Customer.Name when not in edit mode.

The reason I am setting the column property to the Customer object is because I am using a ComboBox Editor Template inside of this column when the grid is in Edit Mode. I believe this is the only way to do it [as per this documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/templating/editor-templates#configuration-Create).

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(x => x)
    .Placeholder("Select a customer...")
    .DataValueField("Id")
    .DataTextField("Name")
    .BindTo((List<CustomerViewModel>)ViewData["customers"])
)
```

With the above setup everything works except for the fact that Sorting/Filtering are broken because of the Customer column.

Since I believe there is no way I can tell the grid to use Customer.Name for Sorting/Filtering instead of Customer. Is there anyway I can still achieve the ComboBox Editor Template with a flat view model?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing "columns.Bound(c => c.Customer)" to columns.Bound(c => c.Customer.Name)

That will make the filtering and sorting work because of the "Name" being a simple type.

On the Editor Template Combobox, give it the name of "Customer", so .Name("Customer)

This worked for me and I had the exact same issue as you, followed Telerik's documentation for Editor Templates but sorting/filtering broke. If it works for you, I am 90% sure that it's because the kendo framework matches the DataValueField "Id" to the "Id" property of the Customer column object EVEN IF you are specifying Customer.Name itself as the bound field.

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer you may want to hear but if you change

`.Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))`

[image]

to

`.Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu))`

[image]

Filtering should work. I *think* this is a bug but won't know until they their support team gets back to me.